# Charging by conduction

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, charge

I learnt that excess electrons move from a negatively charged body to another neutral/positively charged body when the two bodies are touching each other. Why does this occur? What causes this?

Comment: Hello! Please avoid writing titles in capslocks only since this is usually perceived as rude. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Electrons repel each other and are attracted by a positive charge.